# Pandas If Some of Multiple Conditions True (Boolean Math?)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

So I have a data frame with 6 columns of floats `(>= 0, <= 100)` and I need to select every row where at least 4 of those columns are greater than 15.

I could write a really, really, long if statement to cover every single possibility but I feel there's a much more efficient solution. I found a similar solution in R that could solve my problem that works like this:

```
if(((x >= 15) + (y >= 15) + (z >= 15) + (i >= 15) + (j >= 15) + (k >= 15)) >= 4)
```

Does Python and/or Pandas have anything similar?

It would obviously need to work in the `df[(condition) & (condition)...]` format as well.

Comment: Every row where at least 4 of those 6 columns are greater than or equal to 15

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to filter for rows with at least 4 values greater than 15, you can use Boolean indexing:

```
# first identify numeric columns, if necessary
num_cols = df.select_dtypes(include='number').columns

# apply conditional filter
res = df[(df[num_cols] > 15).sum(1) >= 4]

# alternative syntax
res = df[df[num_cols].gt(15).sum(1).ge(4)]
```

The idea is to construct a Boolean dataframe `df > 15`, sum by row via `pd.DataFrame.sum`, then construct a Boolean series by comparing to `4`.

Comment: So if my dataframe is expanded to, say, 10 columns with extra info, such as strings, how do I get those 6 columns? Would it be similar to lexual's solution but with 2:7 in the first parameter? I tried that but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[:, (df > 15).sum() >=4]
```

## for subset of columns

```
columns_to_consider = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df.loc[:, ((df[columns_to_consider] > 15).sum() >=4).index]
# or
df[columns_to_consider].loc[:, (df[columns_to_consider] > 15).sum() >=4]
```

Comment: So if my dataframe is expanded to, say, 10 columns with extra info, such as strings, how do I get those 6 columns? Would it be similar to yours but with 2:7 in the first parameter? I tried that but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: When I do the subset, I get "Unalignable boolean series provided as indexer..."